# In angular.js array not being set correctly when concatenating two arrays

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My code is the following.

On my HTML:

```
<div class="card" ng-repeat="elevation in elevations" ng-click="onListElementClick($index)">

        <h1>
            {{elevation.product}}
            <span class="icon" ng-class="getElementClass($index, true)"></span>
        </h1>
        <h2>
            {{elevation.date}} EID {{elevation.Id}}
            <span ng-class="getElementClass($index, false)">{{elevation.status}}</span>
        </h2>
        <h2 class="contact">
            {{elevation.partnerName}}
            <span class="icon typcn-phone big" ng-click="callPartnerEngineer($index); $event.stopPropagation()"></span>
        </h2>
    </div>
```

On my controller:

```
if(loadMore){
     $scope.elevations = $scope.elevations.concat(elevationList);
}else{
     $scope.elevations = elevationList;
}
```

**Problem:**

When the *else* statement is executed and sets *$scope.elevations = elevationList*, all works well and when clicking over the element the *onListElementClick* I can access into the object properties.

The problem is when the *if* statement is executed and sets *$scope.elevations = $scope.elevations.concat(elevationList)*, the concatenations is done correctly but when the onListElementClick is executed, an error is produced and can't access to the object properties.

It seems that some kind of binding problem is causing this, because it only happens when a concatenation between two arrays is done, if the concatenation is not done all works well.

I have tried to concatenate the arrays using multiple ways but no one worked.

Thank you very much for your response.

Comment: can you make a demo?

Comment: If you face some error, then please add error detail to question.